# ValueError: character U+6573552f... Py2aap

Tags: python-3.x, py2app

I made a very simple program and I'm trying to export it to an app file. I'm currently using Python 3.6 and py2app to convert the py file into app.
So I created the setup file:

```
from setuptools import setup
OPTIONS = {'iconfile':'sc.icns',}

setup(
    app = ['hello.py'],
    options = {
        'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires = ['py2app']
    )
```

and then in the terminal I enter:

```
python3 hello_setup.py py2app
```

After some seconds it creates the dist folder and in it there is the hello.app, the problem is when I run it, it appears a window that says "*hello error*" then I open the .exec file inside the application to see the terminal and it shows this error:

> ValueError: character U+6573552f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]

Why does it appear? How do I fix it? Thank you very much.

In case that it is needed, here is the code of 'hello.py'

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

def printworld():
    messagebox.showinfo('Hello', 'Hello World')

button1 = Button(root, text='Press me!', command=printworld)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8):

This is an issue with the latest version of `py2app==0.14`.

You should open a issue with them to get it fixed in current version. In the meantime you can go back one version and it will work fine

```
pip install py2app==0.13
```

[image: py2app 0.13]

Comment: Man! I just lost 20 minutes for tweaking my Tcl/TK or python setup. Thanks for saving me from losing another couple of hours!